# SSH public key error

Tags: debian, ssh, arch-linux, iptables, openssh

I'm trying to SSH from Debian (Jessie, installed as chroot environment in Chrome OS) to Arch on the same network, and I keep getting an error saying the connection was refused because of a public key error.

Comment: Post the text of the error.

Comment: Could you also add the output of `ssh -v arch_ip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1

### Enable password authentication on Server (your computer running arch-linux)

Edit the SSH configuration file on the server to allow password authentication.

```
[user@arch]$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

> PasswordAuthentication yes
>
> ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

*Use your favorite text editor instead of `nano`, such as `vim`. To use `vim`, once it opens the file, hit <kbd>i</kbd> to switch to insert mode make your edits then press <kbd>esc</kbd> to leave insert mode and type `:wq` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to write changes and quit.*

*Note: `sudo` is not part of the initial installation of arch-linux. As an alternative login to root with `su`.*

Now if key authentication fails you will be prompted to enter your password for the user account on the arch computer.

## Option 2

### Generate key and send to Server

```
[you@debian]$ ssh-keygen
[you@debian]$ ssh-copy-id user@arch-hostname
```